# Double-slit experiment several "observers"?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, observers

In the double-slit experiment, what happens if instead of 1 measuring instruments per slit, you have 100 measuring instruments on one slit observed by 100 people, and one measuring instrument on the other?

What would the results be from both slits?

Answer (score 1):

The number of people observing the experiment will have no effect on the outcome. The effect of having lots of detectors would depend upon their physical characteristics and how they were arranged, etc, as the presence of one detector might block the view of another etc, or indeed might interrupt the propagation of the incident waves. However, in principle, the overall diffraction pattern produced in a well-designed experimental set-up should be the same regardless of how many devices are measuring it.